# PayPal sandbox Merchand id

Tags: paypal

Where can I find the MerchantId in a PayPal Sandbox for a Business account?

I need it to fill the merchant_id property for a Payee object (a third party who will receive part of a payment via credit card), which is then added to a Transaction.
I use the .NET SDK but it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and login using your sandbox account credentials. If you need to reset the password, you can do that via the dashboard of the developer site (https://developer.paypal.com)

Once you login, click "Profile" near the top. Your Merchant Account ID will either be listed near the top, or about 2/3rds of the way down the screen.